# SQL table results for previous day not accurate

Tags: sql-server-2008, datetime-format

I had the following query running in a package setup that gets the records for the previous day in a table that includes the following columns:

```
url, author, dateadded
```

Now the dateadded is in datetime format as follows 2012-08-23 23:58:42.000 and the query as follows:

```
SELECT [authorUrl],[author],
[dateadded]
FROM [Feeds].[dbo].[DataFeed]
where dateadded  > dateadd(day,datediff(day, 0, getdate()-1), 0)  
and dateadded  < dateadd(day,datediff(day, 0, getDate()), 0)
```

Now the count of this query does not match the count of the following query which I would have to alter each day to insert the dates:

```
SELECT [authorUrl]
  ,[author]
       ,[dateadded]
FROM [Feeds].[dbo].[DataFeed]
where dateadded > '2012-08-22 23:59:59' and dateadded < '2012-08-23 23:59:59'
```

Is there something I am missing here?

Perhaps I should emphasize that the dateadded column is one that I edit(inserted from the app) and not an auto inserted date by sql itself.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Stop using weird edges and needlessly complex expressions for date ranges. Since you are on 2008, the proper way to get yesterday is:

```
DECLARE @d DATE = SYSDATETIME();

SELECT ... FROM ... 
  WHERE DateAdded >= DATEADD(DAY, -1, @d) 
  AND DateAdded < @d;
```

Or you can take advantage of the fact that SQL Server 2008 makes this query sargable (which doesn't work in almost every other case you could imagine):

```
SELECT ... FROM ...
  WHERE CONVERT(DATE, DateAdded) 
    = DATEADD(DAY, -1, CONVERT(DATE, SYSDATETIME()));
```

Comment: appreciate the response, the first suggestion does not work for me as I get for example 500000 records back (and I do not understand why; perhaps I should emphasize that the dateadded column is one that I edit and not an auto inserted date by sql) and when I use the hardcoded date query I get the 2000000 records as I expect. Now the second suggestion was better but about 30000 short.

Comment: What is the data type of the DateAdded column? You say "datetime format" but is the data type really datetime? If these two queries return different results then there is either something seriously wrong with your table or query, or there is information you're not telling us.

Comment: the dateadded column has the datatype datetime format. I just think I found the issue. When testing your queries I had a group by clause added and when I removed that the results were fine. So thanks a bunch.